# Why doesn't Ruby have a GUI?

Tags: ruby

Ruby is hard when all they have is a command prompt. Any idea as to what I might be doing wrong? None of the tutorials mention about opening a program with a GUI although they explain the code as if you already have one opened.

Comment: Are you talking about writing a GUI application with Ruby or are you talking about an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for writing the code?

Comment: Try on these [shoes](http://shoesrb.com/). Or if it's an IDE you're looking for, [dig deeper](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

Comment: IDE is what I am referring to.  I said GUI because GUI is a "Graphic User Interface" which in technical terms means a user interface with file options, open, new, etc... not command.  But yes, I meant IDE.  I downloaded Ruby with the Ruby Installer for windows and it just put command prompt version of Ruby on my computer.

Comment: Thank you.  RubyMine looks like what I am looking for.  I can't believe none of these tutorials have mentioned anything about IDE.  When I learned C++ it was like the third paragraph IDE was brought up with a download link. lol

Comment: In practice, relatively few people use an IDE when developing with Ruby or Rails -- I don't think it's so much a Ruby/Rails thing as an interpreted language thing. I found the use of text editors very common when I worked with Tcl and Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might be getting a programming language (Ruby) mixed up with an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Elicpse, Netbeans or Visual Studio which are all graphical interfaces (GUIs) that help you write programs (in Java, C++, Ruby etc).

Because Ruby is an interpreted language with a powerful command line interface REPL (read–eval–print loop) I'd say that most people would say the best way to learn Ruby is to get familiar with the command line and fire up the interpreter and start playing.  Using the interpreter will allow you to start from the basics like just running `2+2` and seeing the result instantly.

If you don't feel comfortable diving in to a command line then perhaps you could try something like [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) IDE. There will be a learning curve for that as well so perhaps if you just want to start from the absolute basics maybe try using the [Try Ruby website](http://tryruby.org/).  It provides a web based "console" for you to try out and learn the ruby basics.

Finally, if you do want to learn ruby the best way, and you are on Windows then I suggest downloading [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) and running the Ruby interpreter there.  There are plenty of tutorials on how to get cygwin and ruby installed, [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Installing_Ruby#Windows) provides a good start.

Comment: But you can't create files and `require` files in command from what I see.  When I do what the tutorials say in command I just get errors.  When I did C++, an IDE made creating the programs and compiling them simple.  Now if I want to find out if port 80 was open, I would go to command prompt. I'm confused as to how a program can be written in command prompt.  Also, I have knowledge and the ability to use Linux (Ubuntu) if that is suggested.

Comment: Assuming you have ruby already installed (sudo apt-get install ruby) you can either use vim (command line editor) or gedit (gui editor) to create files and then run them using `ruby myfile.rb`

Hope that helps.